# Search function for virtuemart

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

please could you advice me if there is some mistake in process of creating this page?
I would like to do search component for virtuemart and I use one php file, where I have written whole code. I want to add there new conditions to $compare2 variable using array variable send2[] and by adding new select options. Please do you have any suggestions? I am not an expert. Thanks

```
<?php

       $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

     if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
       $compare1 = $_POST['send1'];
       ?>
       ?>
       <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
       <?php
       for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($compare1);$i++) {

       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM auto_virtuemart_products WHERE '$compare1[$i]' LIKE product_sku");
       ?>


       <?php
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      ?>
      <tr>
      <td>
      <?php echo $row['product_sku'];?>
      </td>
      <td>
      <?php echo $row['product_weight'];?>
      </td>
      </tr>

      <?php
      }

       }
       ?>

       </table>
       <?php
       echo "<input type='button' value='spat' onclick=location.href=''>";
        }

    else
    {

    ?>


    <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">


    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM auto_virtuemart_products");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>

    <select>
    <option><?php echo $row['product_sku']; ?></option>
    </select>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="send2" value="<?php echo $row['product_sku'] ?>" />

    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </table>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit2" value="Vyber"/></form>

    <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">


    <?php

     if (isset($_POST['Submit2'])) {
       $compare2 = $_POST['send2'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM auto_virtuemart_products WHERE '$compare2' LIKE product_sku");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $row['product_sku']; ?></font>
    </td>
    <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $row['product_weight']; ?></font>
    </td>
    <td>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="send1[]" value="<?php echo $row['product_sku'] ?>" />

    </td>
    </tr>



    <?php
    }
     }

     else
     {
        echo "Empty";

     }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    </table>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/></form>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, please clarify what the problem is and where it happens (this is too much code really)

Comment: `name="send1[]"` What does that mean?

Comment: Just so you know, you're using an unsanitised/unvalidated user input in an SQL string (`$compare1 = $_POST['send1'];`)  This is a recipe for disaster.  Always verify that user input is safe before using it for anything, also you might want to look into prepared statements. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: GordonM // I want to solve security problems after preparing of structure of search page. I think it is possible to solve it later, no?

Comment: Pekka // I have not any problem with functionality of code. I want to ask you for some suggestions, if this is possible way how to made search module.